# Dynamic Footer in React-Table Based on Filtered Data

Tags: react-table

Is there a way to have the footer in React-Table update based on the filtered data? I am trying to put a footer that sums a column and changes as the data is filtered.

***Update:
I added an answer below of how I got this to work. You can also view the full code of my working table here:
https://github.com/travisdock/pf-frontend/blob/master/src/components/table.js

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For anyone curious how I ended up doing it here is my code:

```
Footer: columnProps => {
        return(
          <span>
            {columnProps.data.length > 0 ? this.sumEntries(columnProps.data) : 0}<br></br>
            {columnProps.data.length > 0 ? this.averageEntries(columnProps.data) : 0}
          </span>
        )
      }
```

It turns out Footer can receive a prop of columnProps which has the current data displayed in the table and updates when a filter changes the data. I added a total and an average value to two lines of my footer and it works wonderfully.

Answer (score 0):

Of course there is!
Just use a state attribute as content of the footer. Now if you alter this portion of the state, react will render all components (again) that use that state attribute. For more information please read "[State and Lifecycle](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html)" from the react documentation.

Comment: Whoops, I was updating my state incorrectly. Thanks for your answer, Marco.